# Datapoint to show X and Y value on chart

Tags: c#

This should be easy, I just can't find it:

I find a datapoint in a series given some rules, I then want to show that point on the chart, at the moment it shows only the Y value. I need it to show both X and Y values, something like **-1506;409**

(X axis value = -1506, Y axis value = 409)

To display the datapoint I have at the moment:

```
            datapoint.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Serif", 7);
            datapoint.LabelFormat = "#,#";
            datapoint.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

datapoint, of course is:

```
Datapoint datapoint
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice overview of Labels in Chart controls is here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx).

Here is an example at work; the first line labels each point in a whole series, the second line only one point in another series:

```
chart1.Series[3].Label = "Y = #VALY\nX = #VALX";
chart1.Series[1].Points[5].Label =  "Y = #VALY\nX = #VALX";
```

[image]

A less crowded altenative may be setting tooltips, which only show up when the mouse is over the datapoint:

```
 chart1.Series[2].ToolTip = "Y = #VALY\nX = #VALX";
```

For more ways to include data values do look into the chart [Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx)!!

Comment: you did not address the specific datapoint question. However I was able to apply the: .Label="Y = #VALY\nX = #VALX"; to the datapoint which works.

Comment: _you did not address the specific datapoint question._ Huh? The 2nd line addresses just this case of a single datapoint. doing it via a reference or the points collection is the very same.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Taw's code, its easy, just append the format to your specific datapoint:

```
datapoint.Label = "Y = #VALY\nX = #VALX";
```